# Разместить div над iframe

Tags: html, css, javascript

Есть ifame с определенным размером, заведомо неизвестно где он будет находится на странице, как мне вывести нужный див поверх этого iframe ?

Хочу таким образом отследить клик по "псевдо iframe", т.е. настоящий клик по диву который сверху будет, показать баннер в этом диве и спрятать его. Помогите советом как это можно сделать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать jQuery.position(), чтобы отследить позицию ifram'а по «x» и «y» и спозиционировать туда ваш div. Так же нужно событие $(window).on('resize', …); чтобы при ресайзе перепозиционировать ваш div на новые координаты.